# "SD Card" permission appears on 2.0 devices?

Tags: android

I wrote an Android application. These are the permissions I requested:

- INTERNET
- ACCESS-COARSE-LOCATION
- ACCESS-FINE-LOCATION
- ACCESS-NETWORK-STATE
- CHANGE-NETWORK-STATE

On 1.5 devices, it looks fine. I tried on a 2.0 device, and it also shows an additional permission when installing the app:

- SD CARD READ / WRITE

Is that just coming up by default now on any 2.0 device we install apps on? I do use `Context.openFileOutput()` to write a file to disk, but only to the app sandbox location, never to SD card.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#DONUT), applications targeting DONUT or higher:

> ...must explicitly request the
>   `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to
>   be able to modify the contents of the
>   SD card. (Apps targeting earlier
>   versions will always request the
>   permission.)

Hence, if you are building a 1.5 app, you automatically get `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Ok, so I do need to write to disk, but only a very small file, and for that I only write to the app's sandbox (not SD card). It is a 1.5 app. So if I want to get rid of that permission request coming up, I should create another build specifically for 2.0? Then it should not appear anymore, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think reading from the SDcard is always allowed, but for writing you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, maybe "SD CARD READ / WRITE" is just another translation for that on the device, since it more human readable.